GroupBox Border doesn´t match the Header
I use a TextBlock within my GroupBox.Header to split my text across multiple lines. However, this means that the border is no longer exactly aligned with the text. The text extends beyond the GroupBox and the GroupBox does not adapt to the size of the text.
<GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 5, 0, 0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Red">
  <GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock>
      Entnahmen für <LineBreak/>
      negative Befundung <LineBreak/>
      scannen
    </TextBlock>
  </GroupBox.Header>
  <TextBox />
</GroupBox>

What I want it to look like:

How it currently looks:

I also tried replacing the TextBlock with a StackPanel.

I don't have a clean solution but playing with the padding and margin reaches the desired outcome :
    <GroupBox
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,5,0,0"
        Padding="0,30,0,0" //Added padding
        BorderBrush="Red"
        FontSize="12"
        FontWeight="Bold">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,30,0,0"> //Added margin
                Entnahmen für<LineBreak />
                negative Befundung<LineBreak />
                scannen</TextBlock>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBox />
    </GroupBox>


You could define a reusable style with a custom template for the GroupBox:
<Style x:Key="customGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,6,0,0">
                        <UIElement.OpacityMask>
                            <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7">
                                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <BorderGapMaskConverter />
                                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Header"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </UIElement.OpacityMask>
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3">
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="Header" Padding="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="true"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

Sample usage:
<GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 5, 0, 0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Red"
    Style="{StaticResource customGroupBoxStyle}>
  <GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock>
      Entnahmen für <LineBreak/>
      negative Befundung <LineBreak/>
      scannen
    </TextBlock>
  </GroupBox.Header>
  <TextBox />
</GroupBox>


